# How to make input field of password turn into asterisk?

Tags: java

I'm trying to make the input field turn into ***** when user enters their password. But here I'm getting 2 errors as shown below. How can i solve this. Could someone help modify this code so it works as it should. Thank you.

```
//package com.company;
```

[image: Description of error]

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.Console;
public class Main {
    static void myPassword(){
        String Username = "wisdom";
        String Password = "123";
        boolean granted = false;

        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
            Console console = System.console();
            char[] password = console.readPassword("Enter password");  
            Arrays.fill(password, '*');
            String username = input1.next();

            Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter Password : ");
            String password = input2.next();

            if (username.equals(Username) && password.equals(Password)) {
                granted = true;
                break;
            }
            else if (username.equals(Username)) {
                System.out.println("Invalid Password!");
            } else if (password.equals(Password)) {
                System.out.println("Invalid Username!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid Username & Password!");
            }
        }

        if(granted)
            System.out.println("Access Granted! Welcome!");
        else
            System.out.println("Access Denied! You have reached the maximum number of attempts");
            System.exit(0);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        myPassword();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the errors are self explanatory here.

for first error : `Arrays.fill(password, '*');` , the following import statement is missing.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
```

for second error: `String password = input2.next();` , variable password is already defined at line `char[] password = console.readPassword("Enter password");` . Simply a different variable name needs to be used here.

Answer (score 2):

First error: you need to import `Arrays` before you can use it:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
```

Second error: you initialized a `password` variable here already:

```
char[] password = console.readPassword("Enter password");
```

Choose another variable name instead for:

```
String password = input2.next();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe You can understand why occured errors by answers. Therefore I suggested my source code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.Console;

public class Main {
    static void myPassword(){
        String username = "wisdom";
        String password = "123";
        boolean granted = false;

        Console console = System.console();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter username : ");
            // i suggested variable should distinguished by name
            String inputUsername = scanner.next();
        
            char[] passwordChar = console.readPassword("Enter password");  
        
            // this need import java.util.Arrays;
            // and if use this element of passwordChar[] changed *
            //Arrays.fill(passwordChar, '*');
        
            String inputPassword = new String(passwordChar);

           if (username.equals(inputUsername) && password.equals(inputPassword)) {
                granted = true;
                break;
            }
        
            else if (username.equals(inputUsername)) {
                System.out.println("Invalid Password!");
            } else if (password.equals(inputPassword)) {
                System.out.println("Invalid Username!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid Username & Password!");
            }
        }
        //If you don't need to use scanner
        //You had better close scanner
        scanner.close();
    
        if(granted)
            System.out.println("Access Granted! Welcome!");
        else
            System.out.println("Access Denied! You have reached the maximum number of attempts");
            System.exit(0);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        myPassword();

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting a exception

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.io.Console.readPassword(String, Object[])" because "console" is null
 at com.company.Main.myPassword(Main.java:19)
 at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:53)

Comment: console needs terminal. can you research terminal?